# asp:ImageButton click using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

**UI**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" AlternateText="AddNew"
     ImageUrl="../images/add.png" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
<asp:Image ID="imgProceed" ImageUrl="~/Images/proceed.gif" runat="server"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;"); //Adding client event to avoid submit for some validation purpose
imgProceed.Attributes.Add("onclick", "proceed('" + btnAdd.ClientID + "')");
```

**JavaScript**

```
function proceed(buttonId)
{
    document.getElementById('<%=btnAdd.ClientID%>').removeAttribute("onclick");
    document.getElementById('<%=btnAdd.ClientID%>').click();
}
```

I tried with the above code. I want to `click` the ImageButton through JavaScript. But it is not working. I want to fire server side `"btnAdd_Click"` event by clicking image button.

Comment: When you debug the JavaScript in the browser, what happens?  Is the element found?  Is there an `onclick` attribute to remove?  What's in that attribute?  Are you also removing the click handler which invokes the postback?  (That would explain the behavior you're seeing of not invoking the postback.)

Comment: Why you want to fire btnAdd_Click by javascript? It should get fired anyway if you have handler in codebehind. Second things why you are removing  document.getElementById('<%=btnAdd.ClientID%>').removeAttribute("onclick");
?

Comment: @Amit I added the "onclick" attribute from code behind. before proceed to continue, I need to remove the onclick attribute. right? Otherwise it will not proceed because of "return false;" statement.

Comment: You're doing something weird. Why do you add client click handler only to remove it later? Just set it to function that does client side validation and return true/false depending on validation result

Comment: This is the scenario for me. I want to make the image button click using javascript.

Comment: @Wiizl - He is already in click event when it comes to proceed. Just return true wil also do the posttback natural way. Javascript is not at all required in his scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it up to call a javascript method called proceed

```
imgProceed.Attributes.Add("onclick", "proceed('" + btnAdd.ClientID + "')");
```

but your javascript method is actually called proceedToAdd

```
function proceedToAdd(buttonId)
```

Comment: I immediately corrected it... Please check the changes

Answer (score 0):

Try below code-

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" AlternateText="AddNew"
     ImageUrl="../images/add.png" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
<asp:Image ID="imgProceed" ImageUrl="~/Images/proceed.gif" runat="server"/>
```

Code behind-

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
      {
         //Code to handle click
      }
```

As per your code you are attaching onclick event to Proceed function. So if it is coming in proceed function means button already clicked. No need to click it again.

From other javascript code if you want to click then below line is sufficient.

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnAdd.ClientID%>').click();
```

Also dont need below line of code

```
btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
```

This decision you can take in Proceed function. If you return true in Proceed function then it will submit to server. If you return false it will be on client showing validation message you want.